# Guardar input price en formato number para que firestore lo reconozca como number y no como string - reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**como puedo Guardar input price en formato number para que firestore lo reconozca como number y no como string, ya que asi como esta cuando guardo el input price queda en firestore como tipo string.

He intentado de muchas formas y no lo he podido lograr **

```
function Contenido() {

const[name,setName] = useState('')
const[price,setPrice] = useState('')
const[error,setError] = useState('')
const[usuario, setUsuario] = useState([])

const setUsuarios = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

const usuario = {
    name:name,
    price:price
}

try{
  const data = await store.collection('productos').add(usuario)
  console.log('Tarea añadida')
}catch(e){

    console.log(e)

}

}

  return (
         
           <form onSubmit={setUsuarios} className="form-group">

                    <input onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el nombre" />
                    <input onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}} type="number" className="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Introduce el precio" />
                    <input type="submit" value="registrar" className="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-3" />

                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Además de todos los comentarios y la respuesta de los colegas de la comunidad, hay otra situación que hace que el caso sea de interés.

El problema puede ser originado desde el mismo atributo `value` del `input` tag.

Consideremos la siguiente pieza de código:

```js
function App(){
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState('');

  const setUsuarios = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //el atributo value es de tipo string
    console.log(typeof price)
  }
  return(
    
      <form onSubmit={setUsuarios}>
        <input
        type="number"
        value={price}
        onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}}></input>
        <input type="submit" value="registrar" />

      </form>
  
  )

}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Como se puede observar dentro del método `setUsuarios`, el valor del `input`, mapeado en el estado react `price`, viene como tipo `string`, **aunque se haya especificado su atributo `type` como `number`...(╯°□°）╯**.

Yo también esperaba recibir el valor como `number`, pues se supone que el tipo ya se especificó en el `input`.

Y efectivamente, si se revisa [alguna documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp), el atributo `value` del tag `input`, es de tipo `text`.

Entonces, es necesario que se haga un [Cast](https://isaaccomputerscience.org/concepts/prog_string_casting), para transformar el tipo de dato antes de enviar a DB (Firestore):

```
//puede que aqui funcione, verifica de tu lado
const usuario = {
    name:name,
    price:Number(price)
}
```

#### Notas de campo

- Al trabajar con `forms` en ReactJs, debemos verificar cuidadosamente el tipo de dato, antes de enviar a base de datos y aplicar Cast de ser necesario. Imaginemos un caso así en producción.
- Hay que verificar que tipo de dato numérico se configuró en `firestore`(Int, float, etc) para `price`, aquí solo se propuso el cast con `Number` para ejemplificar el caso.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: me funciono muchas gracias, solo agregue price:Number(price)

Comment: Que bien colega, si consideras que la respuesta fue de ayuda, marcala como aceptada, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Problema radica al inicial el valor del precio como cadena:

`const [price,setPrice] = useState('')`

Inicial el precio como numero:

`const [price,setPrice] = useState(0)`

Ademas no veo el `value` del input con `price`, te recomiendo agregarlo:

`<input value={price} onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}} type="number" className="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Introduce el precio" />`

Espero que so solucione tu problema.

Comment: no funciona , sigue guardando en firestore como string

Comment: @Giovanny, no se que es firestore, pero edite la respuesta de lo que aun te falta por agregar en el input, que puede ser motivo de tu problema.

Comment: osea cuando guardo en una base de datos de firebase el campo input me guarda como string y lo necesito como number, y con la opción que me diste persiste el problema

Comment: Explica eso en tu pregunta, entonces el problema no es de react, el problema esta en firebase. no muestres codigo de react porque nada tiene que ver, quiza tengas que mostrar la parte de tu `collection`

Comment: Es problema puede estar en cualquiera de las 2 partes, después de todo firestore almacena lo que recibe, si recibe un string entonces lo va guardar como un string. Para saber si devuelve o no un string o un número procura hacer un console.log para verificar desde el dev tools del navegador... En caso de ser string podrías parsearlo a numero en el mismo setPrice